# How to refer to specific cell when looping through named range excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I have some code that has been working fine, but I have recently completely rewritten the spreadsheet to use named ranges.

I'm now struggling to rewrite the code to refer to named ranges instead of absolute references. (i think this is the terminology!?)

The File_ref range occupies cells A13:A104
The Already_Input? range occupies cells B13:B104

I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows

The code that works

```
Sub test()
Set mybook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set entrysheet = mybook.Sheets("Entry")

Dim RangeStart As Integer
RangeStart = Range("File_ref").Cells(1).Row

Dim RangeLength As Integer
RangeLength = Range("File_Ref").Count

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim m As Long

j = 0
m = 0

For i = RangeStart To RangeLength + RangeStart

        If IsEmpty(entrysheet.Range("A" & i)) Then 'it's this bit I cannot get to refer to named range

        j = j + 1

        ElseIf entrysheet.Range("B" & i) = "yes" Then

        m = m + 1

        End If

Next i
End Sub
```

The code i have tried, but which doesn't work:

```
Sub test()
Set mybook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set entrysheet = mybook.Sheets("Entry")

Dim RangeStart As Integer
RangeStart = Range("File_ref").Cells(1).Row

Dim RangeLength As Integer
RangeLength = Range("File_Ref").Count

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim m As Long

j = 0
m = 0

For i = RangeStart To RangeLength + RangeStart

        If IsEmpty(entrysheet.Range("File_ref").Cells(i)) Then

        j = j + 1

        ElseIf entrysheet.Range("Already_Input?").Cells(i) = "yes" Then

        m = m + 1

        End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you define the range value as [link](File_ref = "A1:A10"). Also remove the double qoutes from the RangeStart and RangeLenght

Comment: Hi, I didn't see this comment just now. Doesn't this miss the point of using a named range? If the named range moves in the table, then your code will need to be updated. If the code refers to the named range (rather than defining a new range which happens to have the same name) then the code will withstand changes to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code

```
Sub test()
Set mybook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set entrysheet = mybook.Sheets("Entry")

File_ref = "A1:A10"  ''Added new
Already_Input = "B1:B10" ''Added new
Dim RangeStart As Integer
RangeStart = Range(File_ref).Cells(1).Row

Dim RangeLength As Integer
RangeLength = Range(File_ref).Count

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim m As Long

j = 0
m = 0

For i = RangeStart To RangeLength + RangeStart

        If IsEmpty(entrysheet.Range(File_ref).Cells(i)) Then

        j = j + 1

        ElseIf entrysheet.Range(Already_Input).Cells(i) = "yes" Then

        m = m + 1

        End If

 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I understand it you are declaring a new range in VBA called File_ref, whereas I want the code to refer to the existing named range File_ref. I can get it to work if I don't refer to the existing named range, what I'm struggling to do is to translate the code so that it works with my named ranges.

Comment: Use this then File_ref = "A1:A" & entrysheet.Range("A" & entrysheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think we're misunderstanding each other. Maybe I haven't asked the question very well. All I really want to know is whether this is phrased correctly: If IsEmpty(entrysheet.Range(File_ref).Cells(i)) Then. This is the bit that is causing me problems.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, I had misunderstood the range that I was asking the code to evaluate and it was missing all of the sample entries that I had entered to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, I had misunderstood the range that I was asking the code to evaluate and it was missing all of the sample entries that I had entered to test it.